# AWS Amplify: Confirm Signup with Email Verification

Tags: javascript, authentication, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

I'm trying to figure out how to proceed after receiving confirmation email from AWS after signing up using the code below:

```js
import { Auth } from 'Amplify'

const auth() => {
  return Auth.signUp({
    username: email,
    password,
    attributes: {
      birthdate,
      email,
      given_name: firstName,
      family_name: lastName,
    },
  })
}
```

I tried to search for this but didn't find anything helpful so far. Did anyone have experience using Amplify and confirming email address (which is also username in my Cognito configuration)?

The code above works, I get the email, but when click on it I get redirected to `/my-callback-url?username=643663f9-e36b-4333-9222-1118338abf04`. Something like this - what is this username parameter here, how do I decode it?

Best,

Marko

Comment: The documentation doesn't make it clear how to proceed after running Auth.signUp.  If you have verification required in cognito you will get an email or SMS after signup but it's not clear what you are supposed to call when the user provides it.  I would expect something like Auth.verify(123456);

Answer (score 5):

It depends on cognito settings. I set up cognito to return code (not the link like in your case). You need to confirm sign up with  return Auth.confirmSignUp(username, code);

docs are here https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/auth/emailpassword/q/platform/js

I tought that user is confirmed by simply visiting that link in your case. 643663f9-e36b-4333-9222-1118338abf0 is one time verification code.

Comment: It is if multi-factor auth is enabled so user can submit the code from Authenticator for example.

Comment: how can I make it use a link instead of a code?

Comment: @SeanMC

Specifically for Amplify, I answered that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77325856/5666002).